# A WPF combobox showing FontFamilies lists garbage names

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I'm trying to create a WPF font drop down as per [this article by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/LearningWPFWithBabySmashCustomerFeedbackAndAWPFFontComboBox.aspx).

I've encountered an issue (which MS Word seems to handle well) - some fonts do not have appropriate characters to render the name of the font without it being illegible (i.e. Webdings, Windings, Symbol, Bookshelf Symbol 7).

How can I detect this dynamically, and, with WPF, revert to something sensible like Arial?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dynamically, but I think alphabet is in range char(65) to char(100) and if you outside that range for let's say first character of the font name you know you need to revert it or something else you want to do.. Just the idea..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798370/wpf-how-to-filter-out-non-roman-fonts-from-fonts-systemfontfamilies

Comment: @johnyTee given a FontFamily, query its properties to determine if the word “Webdings” is human readable and not a load of weird symbols, then use Arial to render the text “Webdings”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom IValueConverter to set the FontFamily of the ComboBoxItem text. If the font family is symbol based, then the font will not be applied.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.Views.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:PrintableFontFamilyConverter  x:Key="PrintableFontFamilyConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" FontFamily="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PrintableFontFamilyConverter}}" Height="20"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**Converter**

```
public class PrintableFontFamilyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fontFamily = value as FontFamily;

        if (fontFamily != null)
        {
            foreach (var typeface in fontFamily.GetTypefaces())
            {
                if (typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out var glyphTypeface))
                {
                    if (glyphTypeface.Symbol)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return fontFamily;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Dropdown with various font renderings]

Comment: Our team just implemented this, and it worked just great! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts do not carry information if they are readable or not, so one simple solution is to simply add all the nonReadeble fonts(or Readable).

```
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> nonReadebleFonts = new List<string>();
        nonReadebleFonts.Add("Wingdings");
        foreach (FontFamily font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
        {
            ComboBoxItem boxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
            boxItem.Content = font.ToString();
            Uri s = font.BaseUri;
            if (!nonReadebleFonts.Contains(font.ToString()))
            {
                boxItem.FontFamily = font;
            }

            fontsComboBox.Items.Add(boxItem);
        }
```